# unable to provision shared service provider

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2007, shared-service-provider

I am trying to configure Shared services provider in MOSS. We have 2 WFEs and 1 App server. I followed all the steps mentioned by Microsoft for the configuration.but it throws an error at the end "Provisioning failed".

I am using farm account. It has all the privileges required on the database.
but for some reason it doesn't create or configure SSP.

can someone help?

this is the error screen that i get :

[image]

In the logs i am getting this error:

Monitorable Error importing WebPart. Assembly Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=OAssemblyAssemblyVer, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=OAssemblyPublicKey, TypeName. Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ActiveCrawls
06/02/2016 13:41:27.78  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1230)                       0x11E4  Windows SharePoint Services     Web Parts                       7935    Information http://srtmos03:10000/ssp/admin/SearchAdministration.aspx - An unexpected error has been encountered in this Web Part.  Error: This page has encountered a critical error. Contact your system administrator if this problem persists., DesignText:                      Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=OAssemblyAssemblyVer, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=OAssemblyPublicKey                     Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ActiveCrawls                     Active crawls                     This Web Part displays the summary of current active crawls.                     TitleBarOnly                      
06/02/2016 13:41:27.78* OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1230)                       0x11E4  Windows SharePoint Services     Web Parts                       7935    Information ...e>true                      true                      true                 , SourcePreamble: DWP
06/02/2016 13:41:27.78  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1230)                       0x11E4  Windows SharePoint Services     Web Parts                       8l4f    Monitorable Error importing WebPart. Assembly Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=OAssemblyAssemblyVer, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=OAssemblyPublicKey, TypeName. Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CompletedCrawls
06/02/2016 13:41:27.78  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1230)                       0x11E4  Windows SharePoint Services     Web Parts                       7935    Information http://srtmos03:10000/ssp/admin/SearchAdministration.aspx - An unexpected error has been encountered in this Web Part.  Error: This page has encountered a critical error. Contact your system administrator if this problem persists., DesignText:                      Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=OAssemblyAssemblyVer, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=OAssemblyPublicKey                     Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CompletedCrawls                     Recently completed crawls                     This Web Part displays the summary of recently completed crawls.                     TitleBarOnly                ...
06/02/2016 13:41:27.78* OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1230)                       0x11E4  Windows SharePoint Services     Web Parts                       7935    Information ...      true                      true                      true                 , SourcePreamble: DWP
06/02/2016 13:41:27.78  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1230)                       0x11E4  Windows SharePoint Services     Web Parts                       8l4f    Monitorable Error importing WebPart. Assembly Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=OAssemblyAssemblyVer, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=OAssemblyPublicKey, TypeName. Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SystemStatus
06/02/2016 13:41:27.78  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1230)                       0x11E4  Windows SharePoint Services     Web Parts                       7935    Information http://srtmos03:10000/ssp/admin/SearchAdministration.aspx - An unexpected error has been encountered in this Web Part.  Error: This page has encountered a critical error. Contact your system administrator if this problem persists., DesignText:                      Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=OAssemblyAssemblyVer, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=OAssemblyPublicKey                     Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SystemStatus                     System Status                     This Web Part displays status of Search System.                     TitleBarOnly                      true
06/02/2016 13:41:27.78* OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1230)                       0x11E4  Windows SharePoint Services     Web Parts                       7935    Information ...Minimize>                      true                      true Critical The site /ssp/admin could not be created.  The following exception occured: This page has encountered a critical error. Contact your system administrator if this problem persists..